# What's with the Community user?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Suddenly, about 13 hours ago (2:40-3:59 UTC) thirty questions popped to the top of the active questions list.

They all say: `13h ago Community♦ 1`.

Now, I know what Community is (I've read its profile page), but thirty randomly poked questions in one hour? Normally it's less that one a week! I'm supposing they were poked, because there is no other activity on the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those questions were posted on by a spammer that showed up in the past 24 hours. The spam account has since been deleted, but questions cannot be "un-poked", so the Community account assumes responsibility for it.

Also, I believe Community is only supposed to poke questions that have received no upvoted answers.

Comment: I think it may also take credit for other changes prompted by a flag. I flagged a question asking for protection and later it was "protected by community".

Comment: @luserdroog According to "[What is a “protected” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question/52765#52765)", Community protects questions when 3 answers from low-rep users are deleted.  So that could be what happened there.